# MySql variable is null after selecting value

Tags: mysql, sql

i have following problem. When i try to put select result into variable, that variable is null.

select @test = min( testId) from testTable;

The result is null. Any suggestions?

Comment: The question lacks of details. How and where do you run such a query? What do you need to achieve? What is a real task behind your "solution"?

Comment: i need it in stored procedure, but this is null even when i try to run it outside sp. So, if i open new query and type select min(testId) from testTable i get 1 as result, and when i type select @test = min( testId) from testTable the result is null

Comment: how about `SELECT INTO`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html

Comment: the problem was in workbench syntax, the answer bellow is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead:

```
select @test := min( testId) from testTable;
```

EDIT: `=` operator is used in SET statement and for use assign operator in select statement use `:=` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use this syntax:

```
SET @test := (SELECT MIN(testId) from testTable);

SELECT @test;
```

or this:

```
SELECT MIN(testId) FROM testTable INTO @test;

SELECT @test;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7af1/3).